# Can I get the tab host container view programatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I'm adding tabs to my activity in oncreate, I'd like to get the view associated with the tabs so i can edit it manually.

I've tried this but the view is null

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
}

View v = findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

Comment: what do you want to change in the tabs ?!
text or colors or what ?

Comment: You can create fragments associated with each tab then you can edit that manually.